# How do I prove that this map on the quotient space is well defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, commutative-algebra, quotient-spaces

> Let $K$ be a field and $X\subset K^n$. Then define $$\mathcal{O}(X):=K[X_1,...,X_n]\big/I(X)$$ where $I(X):=\{f\in K[X_1,...,X_n]: f(x)=0~~\forall x\in X\}$. I need to show that $$\phi:\mathcal{O}(X)\rightarrow Map(X,K); ~~~~~\bar f\mapsto \left(\phi(\bar f):x\mapsto f(x)\right)$$ is well defined.

My idea was the following:

Let $\bar f,\bar g\in \mathcal{O}(X)$ such that $\phi(\bar f)=\phi(\bar g)$. This means that for all $x\in X$, $f(x)=g(x)$ so $f=g$ in $K[X_1,...,X_n]$ but then $\bar f=\bar g$ in $\mathcal{O}(X)$ and hence $\phi$ is well defined.

Does this work?

Comment: Your proof starts off as if you wanted to show that $\phi$ is injective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't work if $K$ is a finite field, take $K=\mathbb{F}_p$, $f=0$ and $g=x^p-x$, then $f=g$ on $\mathbb{F}_p$ but $f\neq g$. What you can do however : the map $K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\longrightarrow {\rm Map}(X,K)$ that sends $f$ to $x\mapsto f(x)$ is a morphism of rings that vanishes on the ideal $I(X)$ by definition, so it induces a ring morphism $K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I(X)\longrightarrow{\rm Map}(X,K)$ and this map is exactly $\phi$.

Comment: sorry so my proof is wrong but the statement is correct or what? I don't see for what you counterexample is

Comment: The statement is true but your proof isn't. You said that "since $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in X$ then $f=g$" which is false by the counter-example I gave you. In fact you don't need to have $f=g$ to conclude, it is a far too strong argument to conclude that $\overline{f}=\overline{g}$ in $\mathcal{O}(X)$ as we are only interested in the values that take $f$ and $g$. You can have polynomials that take the same values but that aren't the same as I've mentioned.

Comment: ah I see but could you maybe explain me what one then need to show explicitly to proof welldefinedness?

Comment: What I said works. More in line with your method (though you wrote it in reverse, what you wanted to prove there looks like the injectivity of $\phi$) : if $\overline{f}=\overline{g}$ in $\mathcal{O}(X)$ then there exists $h\in I(X)$ such that $f=g+h$ therefore $f(x)=g(x)+i(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in X$ so $\phi(\overline{f})=\phi(\overline{g})$. This is the exact same thing as my answer but written differently : since $\phi$ is a ring morphism, showing that $\overline{f}=\overline{g}\Rightarrow\phi(\overline{f})=\phi(\overline{g})$ is the same as proving that $\phi(f)=0$ for all $f\in I(X)$.

Comment: shouldn't it be $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$?

Comment: Yes you're right, typo.

Comment: Perfect! You seem to understand this a lot. Would it be possible that I ask another question in a couple of minutes and tag you there?

Comment: I can try to answer it.